# Recover deleted VMware virtual disks, i.e. *.vmdk files

Tags: vmware-esx, data-recovery

We had a virtual-disk and its snapshots at the following path on a server.

```
/vmfs/volumes/ESX3/IBSng_Server/
```

The *.vmdk files were:

```
IBSng_server.vmdk 
IBSng_server-flat.vmdk
IBSng_server-000001.vmdk
IBSng_server-000001-delta.vmdk
IBSng_server-000002.vmdk
IBSng_server-000002-delta.vmdk
IBSng_server-000003.vmdk
IBSng_server-000003-delta.vmdk
IBSng_server-000004.vmdk
IBSng_server-000004-delta.vmdk
```

When server was down, we accidently removed some of the *.vmdk files, shown below:

```
IBSng_server-000002.vmdk
IBSng_server-000002-delta.vmdk
IBSng_server-000003.vmdk
IBSng_server-000003-delta.vmdk
```

Now the server doesn't come up. We tried the trial version of DiskInternals VMFS Recovery software, but looks like the software is good at recovering the contents inside the vitual disk, not recovering the *.vmdk files themselves. I wonder if anybody can help. Thanks.

Comment: _"Accidentally removed VMDK files"_ - What did you expect to happen?

Comment: `When server was down, we accidently removed some of the *.vmdk files` - Deploy a new VM and restore from backup.

Comment: Question cross-posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362078/recover-deleted-vmware-virtual-disks-i-e-vmdk-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above, you can not recover the delete files - they are gone. You had to redeploy the virtual machine and restore from backup.

However, as it appears you deleted the snapshot deltas only, **if** the base disk (represented by the `IBSng_server.vmdk` and `IBSng_server-flat.vmdk`) is intact, you can reboot the machine attaching the original `IBSng_server.vmdk` file.

This should be sufficient to restart the machine, but with stale data obviously. At this point, you can restore your backupped data on the now-running machine. With this approach you can reduce the time your machine is offline by skipping OS reinstallation.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting a VMDK file is a bit like removing physical hard drives from a server and throwing them away. Too bad.

Fortunately, this kind of thing is exactly what backups are for! Your best bet is to consult your backup/disaster recovery plan and begin a restore from backup immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but this happened to me recently. I thought I was screwed when Photorec couldn't find it. I was using NTFS and [WinFR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recover-lost-files-on-windows-10-61f5b28a-f5b8-3cc2-0f8e-a63cb4e1d4c4) got it quickly, including the name. I wish Microsoft had developed this tool a long time ago!

Comment: This is not relevant to a discussion about ESX

Comment: It's generally good to know about Windows File Recovery app.

Comment: Then it's a good answer for a different question. And on a different site like [softwarerecs.se], since software recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/574803)